# iOS8 UITableView and Cell - Autolayout Height - Shift / Vertical offset bug on touch and perform segue

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I have an annoying problem with my tableView when i touch a cell which contain an autolayout label (description of the image). The autolayout works well, but, just when i touch the cell before the segue, a cell shifting movement appears (down or up and never the same height).

Don't understand why and this problem is random , I feel it rather happens when a cell is close to appear at the top or bottom.

**Here a video** of the problem on touch / click on the cell and transition to an another view.

http://youtu.be/kJALa8PhD-U

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWzDr.png

Reminds something to someone ?

On IOS8 - Swift, Same problem on my iPhone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Likely what is happening is that because you are using auto layout to get a dynamic height tableviewcell, and iOS is not properly calculating the height of your cells during the segue.  Using either the [estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:) delegate callback (if you have varying heights) or the [estimatedRowHeight](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/estimatedRowHeight) would be my guess at how to fix this.

Doing this should get you two benefits, firstly your views should stop flickering during the segue. Secondly, iOS will not have to look at all of your tableview cells to determine the height of it's scroll indicator (which is good for performance).